# Matplotlib not setting x,y axis ticks at regular interval to dataset maximum

Tags: python, matplotlib

Having a bit of touble with matplotlib and setting the x and y axis ticks.

I have a dataFrame of VO2 and VCO2 data that I want to scatter as x=VO2 and y=VCO2.
It is breath-by-breath (i.e. raw) data so there are >400 data points.
When I do I get x/y labels for all 400 datapoints. Hence I have been trying to set the x/y tick intervals to start at 0.0, and increase 0.5 until the max value of the respective datasets. It needs to by a 'dynamic' plot (i.e. x,y ticks change based on the max values of the data) as it is being incorporated into a larger program.

**Current code:**

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def import_data(fpath):
    with open(fpath, 'r') as f:
        fdata = csv.reader(f)
        fdata = list(fdata)
        df = pd.DataFrame(fdata[1:], columns=fdata[0])
        df.rename(columns=lambda i: i.replace('\'', ''), inplace=True)
        df.columns = [i.lower() for i in df.columns]
        df.t = pd.to_timedelta(df.t).dt.total_seconds()
        df.rename(columns={'t': 't_culm'}, inplace=True)
        df['t'] = df.t_culm - df.t_culm.min()
        df.set_index('t', inplace=True)
        return df


# import data
data = import_data('_data/mpl_data.csv')

if 'vo2' and 'vco2' in data:
    # set x, y variables
    x, y = data.vo2, data.vco2

    # setup figure
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    ax.scatter(x, y)

    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0.0, round(float(x.max())) + 0.5, 0.5))
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0.0, round(float(y.max())) + 0.5, 0.5))

    ax.set_title('V-Slope')
    ax.set_xlabel('V\'O2 (L.min-1)')
    ax.set_ylabel('V\'CO2 (L.min-1)')

    plt.show()
```

**Output:**
[image]

This isn't what I was expecting - the max x and y values are 4.5 and 5.0, respectively. This has restricted the plot to showing the first 10/11 tick labels.

e.g. zoomed in
[image]

Can anyone shed some light on what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
`.head()` and `.tail()` of the dataframe below, can download the .csv file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bb2xixkwld6lh9e/mpl_data.csv?dl=0)

```
     t_culm          vo2         vco2       ve/vo2      ve/vco2    petco2
t                                                                        
0.0   121.0   1.39106827   1.17594794  23.27565131  27.53354881  36.28618
2.0   123.0  1.651732905  1.340260757   21.9176962  27.01129598  39.94186
4.0   125.0  1.661732959  1.304045507  21.89457686  27.90005396  40.41926
7.0   128.0   1.74404014  1.424610552  22.36329263  27.37764362   41.9804
9.0   130.0   1.86141934  1.449644274  20.25671442   26.0106846  41.56256
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
685.0   806.0  4.055829465  4.565977319  31.68991968  28.14926598  137.91915
686.0   807.0  4.144702364   4.70023799  32.09388958  28.30061377  142.30906
686.0   807.0   4.11506417  4.617204706  31.28707468  27.88447301  138.67856
687.0   808.0   4.03808704  4.647029051  31.82453689  27.65428161  137.60385
688.0   809.0  3.808044776  4.323517481  31.20141883  27.48142005  127.28648
```

Comment: Show some test data

Comment: Can you post some of your data?  This is hard to diagnose without seeing your data frames

Comment: edited to show example of data frame and linked to csv file

Comment: I cannot reproduce your output.  Maybe try restarting your kernel?

Comment: Restarted - still same output.  I've updated the code so it now contains the entire script (incl. the import function). Also linked a different .csv file.

Comment: @Serenity Edited to show example data & linked complete csv file used